# DexieJS await count() not working in interation

Tags: dexie

I had been studying and searching without any luck on my following issues:-

```
let groups = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
await groups.map( async (value) => {
  let total = 0;
  if (value > 3) {
    total = await db.table.where({ gender: 'male'}).count();
  }
  console.log(total)  // always show 0
});
```

Please advice how can i resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i tried some mess around with my coding and found out await inside if statement seems to cause the problem which i am not sure is true.
However, i re-code as followed and it seems working at the moment.
I agreed which is definitely the stupidest way but problem need to be patched on deadline.

```
let groups = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
await groups.map( async (value) => {
  let total = await db.table.where({ gender: 'male'}).count();
  if (value < 3) {
    total = 0;
  }
  console.log(total)  // now the result seems accurate
});
```

Please feel free to advice, thank you in advance
nameste